# Why can I not change my email address in my profile?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-profiles, gravatar

I have recently decided to change the email address that my Gravatar is associated with. In the end, I had to create a new Gravatar account with the different email address. After doing this, I successfully changed my email address for my StackOverflow, ServerFault, and AskUbuntu accounts. However, when I attempt to change my SuperUser email address, I get an error saying "Oops! ... Email is already registered". If the email worked in the other accounts, why is it not working here?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you have just associated the second email address with your gravatar account as a secondary address? I'm pretty sure I did this, but its been a while...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've accidentally created two accounts on SU.

The one you've used to post this question - [51597](https://superuser.com/users/51597) - is linked to accounts on the other sites and so is presumably your "main" account.

But there is another account ([51596](https://superuser.com/users/51596)) which has your name and matches your gravatar (implying it is using your email address) of the accounts linked to the first.

You need to get the two accounts merged, I believe the simplest way to do that is to flag one of your own posts of moderator attention asking for a merge and providing *both* your user IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I have merged the two account DMA found into one here:

[Ani Dev](https://superuser.com/users/51596)